# Make Button Clickable on predefined Time + Countdown in Button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, button, countdown

I´m a totally newbie in Javascript.

I´m using Wordpress and need a Button that is getting clickable after a predefined time - Like 2 Hours after Posts.

Here´s what i already have.

```
  echo $post_time = $proposal->comment_date;
  $t_time = get_the_time( __( 'Y/m/d g:i:s A' ) );
  echo "<h1>BLOG TIME</h1>";
  echo $t_time . "<br>";
  echo $current_time = date("Y-m-d g:i:s A");
  $time_to_wait = 60 //Minutes

  if ( $post_time < $current_time )
  {
    echo "ok";
  } else { echo "not ok"; }
```

1. How to integrate the $time_to_wait Variable?
2. How should the JavaScript look like?

Comment: You can solve it by AJAX

Comment: You will want to get timestamp with your PHP. Once your dates are in timestamp covert to minutes and do if($post_time + 60 < $current_time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to integrate the $time_to_wait Variable?

`$post_time` and `$current_time` should be timestamps. `$time_to_wait` should be milliseconds (`60` * 60 * 1000)

Maybe like that: `if ($current_time - $time_to_wait > $post_time) { echo '0'; } else { echo '1'; }`

(if i understood your question correctly)

> How should the JavaScript look like?

Please, describe what do you want? I think it should be like

`echo '<button id="your_button" ' . (($current_time - $time_to_wait > $post_time) ? 'disabled="true"' : ''). '">'` in your php code.

If you want button to be enabled if time has passed. No JS required. Did i answered your question correctly? If not, please response.

(Excuse me for my grammar)

Comment: One small comment: Timestamps in php are in seconds, not microseconds so `$time_to_wait` should be in seconds as well.